# Calling Active Job Using Whenever Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever, rails-activejob

Here is an active job:

```
# app/jobs/upload_evidence_job.rb

class UploadEvidenceJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
    UploadRequest.pull_messages
    ...
  end
end
```

Here is my whenever config file:

```
set :output, "log/cron_log.log"
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']

every 1.minutes do
  runner 'UploadEvidenceJob.perform_later'
end
```

I am running the following command to write in cron which is working fine.

`$ whenever --update-crontab --set environment=development`

The issue is the job is not getting called from the cron, whereas it is working from the rails console.

I think the active jobs are not getting loaded in case of cron, do I need to `require` it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure cron runner is working at all - in cron environment is different, because there's no shell session. For example - if you're using RVM - you need ruby binstubs and may be full path to `bundle` command.
Then try manually running cron command that was generated (see `crontab -l` for user that you're running whenever under)

Also spinning up rails every minute just to enqueue a job - is not very optimal, you can use `sidekiq-scheduler` (if you're using sidekiq) or other ruby scheduler to do so